# Basic relational database concepts

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, relational-database

I am new to RDB. I try to understand some basic concepts of RDB.

Are following statements correct?

1. A database is simply a well-structured file and the only way to access this file is via RDBMS. (except sqlite)
2. The RDBMS a process which manages the database file. When I use SQL statements in my application to query the database, My application sends the SQL statements to the RDBMS by using socket-based IPC.
3. When the RDBMS receives the SQL statements, it parses and executes those statements.
4. A stored procedure is simply SQL statements in a file and it is pre-compiled to speed up the statements

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What IPC mechanisms are used (if any are used at all) is completely independent from the concept of a RDBMS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Not all databases are well-structured ☺, and not all databases are stored in a file.
   SQLite is an RDBMS.
2. The RDBMS is not necessarily a *separate* process, and there are many communication mechanisms other than sockets.
   An embedded RDBMS like SQLite is just a library, and gets statements through normal function calls.
3. Yes.
4. Stored procedures are sets of statements stored *in the database*.
   They are not necessarily pre-compiled. (E.g., SQlite's triggers are not.)